# Visual Studio 2015 won't suppress error C4996

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition gives the following error when compiling in debug, but not when compiling in release:

```
std::copy::_Unchecked_iterators::_Deprecate': Call to 'std::copy' with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'
```

---

I was able to trace back the source of this error to lines 214 and 242 of [this third party library](https://www.partow.net/programming/bitmap/index.html) I'm using to write bitmap images. I don't fully understand what is going on in these parts, so I'd rather not mess with it.

---

I'm trying to disable this error, but Visual Studio won't let me. I've tried the following solutions that were suggested [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-3-c4996?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170), on StackOverflow, or elsewhere:

- Add `4996` to the "Disable Specific Warnings" field in Project Settings > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Advanced.
- Add `/wd4996` to the "Command Arguments" field in Project Settings > Configuration Properties > Debugging.
- Add `#pragma warning (disable : 4996)` at the top of the offending file, and/or above the offending function.
- Add `_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`, `_SCL_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS`, `_SCL_OBSOLETE_NO_WARNINGS`, `_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS_GLOBAL`, and combinations thereof to the "Preprocessor Definitions" field in Project Settings > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor.
- Add the definitions from the previous solution with a `#define` directive to the top of the offending file.
- Add the definitions from the previous solution but prefixed with `/D` or with `-D` to the "Command Arguments" field.

But none of this fixes the issue for me.

---

What could possibly be the reason for Visual Studio to keep insisting on displaying this error?

Comment: Wait, did you try to `#define -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`?

Comment: Is it possible that the whitespace after `#pragma warning` is being problematic? Did you clean the project? Sorry, just throwing ideas out there in case it sticks :/

Comment: @Rakete1111 If I try that it tells me that it "expected an identifier" at the `-`. Without the `-` it still gives the error.

Comment: @meepzh I've tried it with and without spaces after `warning` and around the colon, but it doesn't fix it. Cleaning the solution and the project, and rebuilding doesn't fix it either.

Comment: The msdn documentation page you linked to has a special note (and example) about _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL and [Checked Iterators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965.aspx).

Comment: This still seems to be an problem in VS2017; updating the Configuration Properties didn't work for me, but the `#pragma warning` did work.

Answer (score 5):

## define NO_WARN_MBCS_MFC_DEPRECATION

Comment: Hi, this needs a bit more context to be a useful answer.

Comment: Well, not really, Ben. It doesn't really matter how you define the macro - command line option, #define, whatever. Define this, and the warning goes away

Answer (score 1):

Disabling warning 4996 has no effect on std::copy warnings. To suppress this warning place the following at the top of your source file:

```
#define _SECURE_SCL_DEPRECATE 0
#include <algorithm>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS to preprocessor definitions.

Answer (score 0):

In your stdafx.h:

```
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable: 4996)
#include <algorithm>
#pragma warning( pop )
```

Worked for me VS2015 update 3