# How to disable a false positive error in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have wrote this basic C program:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n = rand();
    int a[n];
    return a[0];
}
```

Which is getting compiled properly in gcc. But MS C/C++ intellisense in showing error squiggles stating `expression must have a constant value C/C++(28) [4, 8]`. After some googling I have found out that MSVC have not implemented VLAs. But I am unable to find a way to suppress this error. Someone please help me out!

**EDIT**: Also, surprisingly it is not warning for implicit declaration of `rand` in line 3 !!!

**EDIT**: If possible, can someone also mention an alternative extension for C/C++.

**EDIT**: I am using:

- Microsoft VSCode v1.63.2 code editor
- Microsoft C/C++ Extension Pack v1.1.10 extension
- MinGW-W64 gcc v8.1.0 compiler

GCC no compilation flags are set.

C/C++ extension is configured with following:

- compilerPath: `C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe`
- cppStandard: gnu++20
- cStandard: gnu17
- intelliSenseMode: `windows-gcc-x64`

Comment: Anyone? Please....! I am desperately trying to find it from 4 hours. :|

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ array - expression must have a constant value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219712/c-array-expression-must-have-a-constant-value)

Comment: @Kamiccolo Nope.. I am using C, and in C, standard allows VLA and gcc implements it. That question is about C++.

Comment: You did not provide almost any information about your development environment. Build flags? Full toolchain with versions, etc? MVSC does not support it according to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5246961/1150918 godbolt fails as well.

Comment: This was fixed for clang: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cc-intellisense-gives-parameter-is-not-allowed-for/1256096

Answer (score -1):

This shows as an error because it indeed is an error. When you're using the `MSVC` compiler it is only going to give you the results from `MSVC` compilation.

Now, this is actually due to the fact that you're doing the wrong thing. It seems that you want to initialize an array with a size `n` which is obtained from a random value. In other words, you should perform a [dynamic allocation](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation), that is, allocation of memory during runtime. Since you are using C, you must use the [malloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) functions for this as shown:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n = rand();
    int *a = malloc(n * sizeof(int));//Dynamic allocation of an array
    int val = a[0];//Garbage value
    free(a);//Deallocation / Free the memory taken by array 
    return val;
}
```

If want to replace `MSVC` with `gcc`, you can change the default compiler of C/C++ in VS code by changing the setting:

Change your setting

```
C_Cpp.default.compilerPath` : C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe
```

EDIT: I mistakenly mentioned that the path should be of the bin folder. Instead, it should be of `g++.exe` itself. I downloaded the latest binary and confirmed it for you.

You can do this by going to the VS code preferences, searching for `C_Cpp.default.compilerPath` in the search bar, which would lead you to the required input box. Enter `C:\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe` and the compilation would replace `MSVC` with `gcc`/`g++`

Finally, try to avoid VLA and use dynamic allocation as it is a safer and much supported practice.

Comment: `This shows as an error because it indeed is an error.` Yes, I know that is an error indeed, but I wanted to know how to suppress that in intellisense.

Comment: Also, the code snippet shown in the question is just a minimal reproducible example for my case. I am using VLA in a different personal project.

Comment: I have changed the settings to add `compilerPath`. But it is showing this: `[29/12/2021, 12:12:23 pm] Unable to resolve configuration with compilerPath "C:\MinGW\bin".  Using "C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe" instead.` And the error still persists.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB You cannot suppress errors, You can only suppress warnings

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB Can you show me the exact path you have entered?

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB I have edited my answer to show another setting, I don't gave GCC installed in my machine so I cannot check on my own. Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Exact path I have entered is `C:\MinGW\bin`. `where gcc` in terminal returns `C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe`. So I hope path I entered is correct.

Comment: I have also changed the `intelliSenseMode`, but still the error persists. At this point, you can also suggest me a good alternative gcc extension for C/C++. I'm fed up with this.

Comment: Check if this edit solves your problem

Comment: Again, sorry, but nope, problem still persists. I've tried both `gcc.exe` and `g++.exe`.

Comment: Also, I may reconsider my usage of VLAs. But I still want to get a solution for this question.

Comment: @AzuxirenLeadGuy *This shows as an error because it indeed is an error*  No it is not.  VLAs were a mandatory part of C99 that Microsoft never bothered to support, and while they are now optional, the are supported by just about every major C compiler other than Microsoft's.  In fact, this very bug in VSCode was fixed for clang recently: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cc-intellisense-gives-parameter-is-not-allowed-for/1256096  Perhaps it's not been fixed for GCC, but I couldn't find a bug report (although my search was admittedly brief).

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes it is not an error in GCC, (that's why it compiles successfully for the OP), but it is an error in the MSVC compiler and that is what I meant